# Can go get command be used to distribute bash scripts?

Tags: go

I am working on a toolkit, consisting of 3 types of files:
1. binaries, compiled from go sources;
2. shell scripts;
3. some data files (yaml, etc).

What's the easiest way to distribute all this across a company, so that:
1. both binaries and shell scripts are immediately available, as commands;
2. shell scripts are under source control, and everyone can push patches right away?

Can *go get* command take care of all this? Or it deals just with go sources?

Ideally, I want to put everything in some git repository, and instruct everyone to just use go get command.

Also, can I use *go get* to set an environment variable or even make some script to execute? Or is it abusing this command?

Comment: Write a script or use a general purpose package manager to distribute the code.

Comment: It would be a good idea to have a look at how go get works and rewrite it for general purpose.